# Excel: Passing the current cell as argument when calling vba function from worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to make a VBA function that accepts a cell as argument and works from there using a variety of Range.Offset. This function will be called in the worksheet cells. For testing I'm using this simple script:

```
Public Function testPublic(targetCell As Range) As Boolean
   targetCell.Offset(0, 3).Value2 = "Test is successful!"
   testPublic = True
End Function
```

To see if I can get the cell reference to work, I pass simple references such as C5, but I only get #VALUE! error. Not sure what's wrong with this.

Tried to change Range as Variant, still doesn't work

Comment: You cannot use a function called as a UDF from a worksheet to update another cell in the worksheet: the function can only return a value to the cell containing the function (an array formula can return multiple values, but again only to the cells where the formula was entered).   For more information see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams apparently that is indeed the problem. I removed the cell manipulation code and it works. Perhaps you can post it as an answer so I can set it as one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use a function called as a UDF from a worksheet to update another cell in the worksheet: the function can only return a value to the cell containing the function (an array formula can return multiple values, but again only to the cells where the formula was entered).

For more information see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1

Comment: the link is dead! :(

Answer (score 0):

Try below calling code

```
If testPublic(targetCell:=Range1) Then
  MsgBox "success"
End If
```

The function code is as below. Change for ByRef and ByVal as per your logic.

```
Public Function testPublic(ByRef targetCell As Range) As Boolean
   targetCell.Offset(0, 3).Value2 = "Test is successful!"
   testPublic = True
End Function
```

Comment: The issue is actually that UDF cannot modify other cells' values. I removed the first line of the code and it works

Comment: Above code on my machine was able to modify the other cell's value i.e. at offset(0,3).

Comment: OP is calling their function from a worksheet formula, not from a Sub.